# My scanner class isn't reading the next line from the .txt file

Tags: android, line, java.util.scanner, delimiter, text-files

I'm trying to read a text file that looks like this

```
0,-16,-4,12,10,4,-14,8,44,8,8,12,-4 
1,-16,-4,12,10,4,-14,6,43,10,10,12,-4
2,-16,-6,10,11,2,-13,4,43,10,11,12,-4
3,-16,-6,10,11,2,-13,6,43,10,11,11,-4
4,-16,-6,10,11,2,-13,6,42,8,10,10,-4
```

However I am only able to the first line then it stops, I'm using the hasNextInt function in a for loop and it reaches the end of the first line and then hasNextInt = null. What method can I use to carry on reading into the next line?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Here's the code:

```
public final static int numChannels = 12;   // the data is stored in 12 channels, one for each lead
public final static int numSamples = 500*6; //500 = fs so *6 for 6 seconds of data
public File file;
private Scanner scanner;
short [] [] ecg = new short [numChannels] [numSamples];

 public ECGFilereader (String fname) throws FileNotFoundException 
 {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/ecg.txt");    

    scanner = new Scanner(file);

    scanner.useDelimiter(",");

}
public boolean ReadFile(Waveform[] waves) // sorts data into and array of an array (12 channels each containing 3000 samples)
{
    for (int m=0; m<numSamples && scanner.hasNextInt(); m++)
    {
        String x = scanner.next();
        for (int chan = 0; chan<numChannels && scanner.hasNextInt(); chan++)
        {
            ecg [chan] [m] = (short) scanner.nextInt();     
        }
    }

    for (int chan=0; chan<numChannels; chan++)
        waves[chan].setSignal(ecg[chan]); // sets a signal equal to the ecg array of channels
    return true;

}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would check for the case when `hasNextInt()` returns false, and add the following:

```
if (!scanner.hasNextInt())
{
    if (scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

This will consume the rest of the line and set the scanner to be at the beginning of the next line.

Comment: that sounds perfect but I can't work out where to put it because I want to run it with the scanner.hasNextInt() but I'm pretty sure that won't work having "ifs" inside a for loop. where would you suggest?

Comment: sorry ignore that last comment that was me just being a little bit stupid. That has worked perfectly, thankyou very much.